# Better way to get RGBA Color Components from UIColor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a quicker (or better) way to get the [RGBA] color components from UIColor? There seem to be a lot of variations of this around (some on here, all essentially similar to what I have done here) I am just curious if there is an alternative as it seems a bit "lacking" given that everything else is usually so complete and well thought out.

```
if([eachKey isEqualToString:@"NSColor"]) {
    UIColor *newColor = [attrs valueForKey:eachKey];
    //NSLog(@"COLOR: %@", newColor);
    CGColorRef colorRef = [newColor CGColor];
    //NSLog(@"%@", colorRef);
    int numComponets = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(colorRef);
    if(numComponets == 4) {
        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(colorRef);
        CGFloat compR = components[0];
        CGFloat compG = components[1];
        CGFloat compB = components[2];
        CGFloat compA = components[3];

        //NSLog(@"R:%f G:%f B:%f, A:%f", compR, compG, compB, compA);
    }
}
```

I am not looking for how (I think I have the long version above) I would just like to know if this is the way your supposed to do this now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
CGFloat r, g, b, a;    
[MyColor getRed: &r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
```

iOS 5+ required.

Comment: Thats a fair bit easier, much appreciated Seva.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/getRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a) method in the class reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)getRed:(CGFloat *)red 
         green:(CGFloat *)green 
          blue:(CGFloat *)blue 
         alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

The method above is not reliable, it'll return NO for `[UIColor whiteColor]` (or other grayscale `color`).

Use

`if(numComponets == 5) {`

instead of

`if(numComponets == 4) {`

#### From api doc:

```
The size of the array is one more than the number of components of the color 
space for the color.
```